# multi store using magento 2 website admin not able to access

Tags: magento2, multistore

I created multi store in magento 2. but not able to access website admin. Kindly help me to get the solution of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully by now you've been able to get into your admin.

If anyone else finds themselves locked out of their Magento 2 admin, here is a simple way to get back in.

Log in with SSH to your server and navigate to your web root. Once there, type the following command:

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-firstname='Admin' --admin-lastname='Admin' --admin-email='youremail@yourserver.com' --admin-user='tempadmin' --admin-password='YoUr!Pas5woR$'
```

After the command runs, you can use this temporary admin account to restore your existing admin account or just continue using this account.

**Adapted from: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-admin.html**

Magento DevDocs are great! It's an excellent resource for problems just like this one.